Linear interpolation on a 2D numpy array along a column
I have a 2D array in the shape of (273, 3). Some of these values are 0 and I need to replace the zeros with a value interpolated alongside the vertical axis for the second and third column.
datatot =  [...
 [19250.0 768.27 20.35]
 [19345.0 770.17 11.32]
 [19433.0 0 0]
 [19545.0 0 0]
 [19679.0 777.25 14.95]
 [19741.0 778.46 14.32]
 [19822.0 780.8 19.01]
 ...]

The goal array should look like this:
datatot =  [...
 [19250.0 768.27 20.35]
 [19345.0 770.17 11.32]
 [19433.0 772.53 12.53]
 [19545.0 774.59 13.74]
 [19679.0 777.25 14.95]
 [19741.0 778.46 14.32]
 [19822.0 780.8 19.01]
 ...]

I tried to look into numpy.interp but I can't really make it work.
datatot = interp1d(datatot[:, 0], datatot[:, 1], fill_value="0", kind='linear')

How could I set up this function?

The function interp1d from scipy doesn't fill the values directly rather it returns a interpolation function that can be used to interpolate missing values, zeros in your case. The parameter fill_value has a completely different purpose. Read the docs here.
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

datatot =  np.array(
 [[19250.0, 768.27, 20.35],
 [19345.0, 770.17, 11.32],
 [19679.0, 777.25, 14.95],
 [19741.0, 778.46, 14.32],
 [19822.0, 780.8,19.01]]
 ) # data that can be used to build a interpolation function
f1 = interp1d(datatot[:, 0], datatot[:, 1]) # interpolation function for column 1, assuming column indices starts with 0
f2 = interp1d(datatot[:, 0], datatot[:, 2]) # interpolation function for column 2
data_to_interpolate =  np.array([[19433.0, 772.53, 12.53], [19545.0, 774.59, 13.74]])
data_column_1 = f1(data_to_interpolate[:, 0])
data_column_2 = f2(data_to_interpolate[:, 0])
print(data_column_1)
print(data_column_2)

You can streamline this function to automatically split data into data (split 1) to build interpolation function and data (split 2) to fill using the interpolation function.
The output looks like:
[772.03538922 774.40952096]
[12.27640719 13.49365269]


interp1d is called that because it wants the input to be 1d. The output can have any number of dimensions, see tio.run

What I'm saying is, you don't need separate interpolators for each column. A single one can do all columns
